# Run command, stream stdout/stderr and capture results

Tags: rust

I'm trying to use [`std::process::Command`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/process/struct.Command.html) to run a command and stream its stdout and stderr while also capturing a copy of stdout/stderr. I found I can use `spawn`.

This code will capture the output, but won't stream it to stdout/stderr while it's happening:

```
let mut child = command
    .envs(env)
    .stdout(Stdio::piped()) // <=== Difference here
    .spawn()
    .unwrap();

let output = child
    .wait_with_output().unwrap();

println!("Done {}", std::str::from_utf8(&output.stdout).unwrap());
```

This code will stream the output but not capture it:

```
let mut child = command
    .envs(env)
    .spawn()
    .unwrap();

let output = child
    .wait_with_output().unwrap();

println!("Done {}", std::str::from_utf8(&output.stdout).unwrap());
```

Is there a way to capture a command's output while also streaming it to the parent stdout/stderr?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is similar to how I stream the compilation and execution output on Rust Explorer.

To stream the output you can pipe the `stdout` and read it line by line using `BufReader`.

[Playground](https://www.rustexplorer.com/b#%2F*%0A%5Bdependencies%5D%0A%0A*%2F%0A%0Ause%20std%3A%3Aio%3A%3ABufRead%3B%0Ause%20std%3A%3Aio%3A%3ABufReader%3B%0Ause%20std%3A%3Aprocess%3A%3ACommand%3B%0Ause%20std%3A%3Aprocess%3A%3AStdio%3B%0A%0Afn%20main()%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%2F%2F%20Compile%20code.%0A%20%20%20%20let%20mut%20child%20%3D%20Command%3A%3Anew(%22bash%22)%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20.args(%5B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22-c%22%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22echo%20%27Hello%27%3B%20sleep%203s%3B%20echo%20%27World%27%22%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%5D)%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20.stdout(Stdio%3A%3Apiped())%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20.spawn()%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20.unwrap()%3B%0A%20%20%20%20let%20stdout%20%3D%20child.stdout.take().unwrap()%3B%0A%0A%20%20%20%20%2F%2F%20Stream%20output.%0A%20%20%20%20let%20lines%20%3D%20BufReader%3A%3Anew(stdout).lines()%3B%0A%20%20%20%20for%20line%20in%20lines%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20println!(%22%7B%7D%22%2C%20line.unwrap())%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%7D)

```rust
use std::io::BufRead;
use std::io::BufReader;
use std::process::Command;
use std::process::Stdio;

fn main() {
    // Compile code.
    let mut child = Command::new("bash")
        .args([
            "-c",
            "echo 'Hello'; sleep 3s; echo 'World'"
        ])
        .stdout(Stdio::piped())
        .spawn()
        .unwrap();
    let stdout = child.stdout.take().unwrap();

    // Stream output.
    let lines = BufReader::new(stdout).lines();
    for line in lines {
        println!("{}", line.unwrap());
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you a ton! One question: this would only stream stdout but not stderr. I’m thinking I could redirect stderr to stdout but ideallly I don’t want to have to do that. Maybe I could output both at the same time in threads? Any other thoughts or ideas?

Comment: @Schneems You can do the same for stderr. First, pipe it `.stderr(Stdio::piped())`. And then stream it from another thread.

Comment: I left another solution with my some code I got working. I accepted your solution though as you cleared my main hurdle. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 5):

There might be a less verbose way to do this, but this is the solution I came up with.

Spawn the process with a piped io for stdout and stderr. Spawn a thread for stdout and stderr. In each thread read from the pipe and output directly to stdout or stderr then write the contents to a channel.

In the main thread wait for the process to finish, then join the threads and finally read each channel to get the contents of stdout and stderr.

```rust
use std::io::BufRead;

let mut child = command
    .stdout(Stdio::piped())
    .stderr(Stdio::piped())
    .spawn()
    .unwrap();

let child_stdout = child
    .stdout
    .take()
    .expect("Internal error, could not take stdout");
let child_stderr = child
    .stderr
    .take()
    .expect("Internal error, could not take stderr");

let (stdout_tx, stdout_rx) = std::sync::mpsc::channel();
let (stderr_tx, stderr_rx) = std::sync::mpsc::channel();

let stdout_thread = thread::spawn(move || {
    let stdout_lines = BufReader::new(child_stdout).lines();
    for line in stdout_lines {
        let line = line.unwrap();
        println!("{}", line);
        stdout_tx.send(line).unwrap();
    }
});

let stderr_thread = thread::spawn(move || {
    let stderr_lines = BufReader::new(child_stderr).lines();
    for line in stderr_lines {
        let line = line.unwrap();
        eprintln!("{}", line);
        stderr_tx.send(line).unwrap();
    }
});

let status = child
    .wait()
    .expect("Internal error, failed to wait on child");

stdout_thread.join().unwrap();
stderr_thread.join().unwrap();

let stdout = stdout_rx.into_iter().collect::<Vec<String>>().join("");
let stderr = stderr_rx.into_iter().collect::<Vec<String>>().join("");
```

The channel isn't strictly needed. I originally wanted to mutate a string, but I'm new in Rust with threads and couldn't find any examples showing how to mutate a string in a thread and then read it back into main.

I'm accepting the other solution as it really answered my main question. I just wanted to post back to give everyone a fully-featured answer that does exactly what I originally asked

Comment: This worked for me but I had to add `use std::io::BufRead;` in each thread otherwise I would get the error "items from traits can only be used if the trait is in scope".
Edit: It also worked with `use std::io::{BufRead, BufReader};` top of the file.